# Scala count non consecutive occurrences of a character in string

Tags: scala

I have a string that contains `"word1-word2----word3--word4"`, I want to count the delimiter which is in this case `-`, but I want to count the repeating instances as `1` (`---` count would be `1`), I used  `line.count(_ == '-')` which gives a count of `7` where I need it to be `3`.

Thanks

Edit: 
I have an array of delimiters as follows

```
  val delimiterMap = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Char, Int]()
  val delimitersList = List(',', ';', ':', '|', '\t','-')
  for (a <- delimitersList)
  delimiterMap += a -> line.replaceAll(a.toString+"+",a.toString).count(_ == a)
```

which when run gives the following error:

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 1
 |+
 ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
 at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
 at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:16)
 at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:15)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  ... 33 elided
```

so I think there is an issue with the replaceAll regex I use

Comment: you may check my answer update to your edit

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't count "-", the total was 0

Comment: my bad it did work but I changed last line to delimiterMap += a ->(a+"+").r.findAllIn(line).length, thanks Evgeny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may split your string into array by regex "-+", which finds one or more occurences of symbol '-', and then count length of array minus one:

```
val s = "word1-word2----word3--word4"
val arr = s.split("-+") // Array(word1, word2, word3, word4)
arr.length - 1 // 3
```

Or, even better, without needing to substract one, just find all occurrences of this regex:

```
"-+".r.findAllIn(s).length
```

**Update due to question edit:**

`|` is special symbol for regex. You should write it as `"\\|"`. Double `\` is needed to make single `\`. Then, change map key type and all delimiters with `String`s instead of `Char`s as well this way:

```
val delimiterMap = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Int]()
val delimitersList = List(",", ";", ":", "\\|", "\t", "-")
```

Comment: I generally prefer `"""\|""""` over `"\\|"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understood the question but you're basically looking to count the delimiters instead of words?

Off the top of my head you could do something like this

```
val s =  "word1-word2----word3--word4"
val nonConsecutiveOccurrences = s.split("[^-]") //filter characters that aren't '-'
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty)//get rid of empty strings
  .map(_.count(_ =='-'))// Array[Int] = Array(1, 4, 2)
```

Doing `nonConsecutiveOccurrences.length` should produce `3`.

This is quite inefficient but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proper regular expression for this.

```
scala> val s = "word1-word2----word3--word4"
// s: String = word1-word2----word3--word4

// now lets use a regex which will match one-or-more "-"
scala> val regex = "-+".r
// regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = -+

scala> val count = regex.findAllIn(s).length
// count: Int = 3
```

Comment: sorry this was meant for another answer.